# Can an external template loaded with the 'include' keyword contain Jinja syntax?

Tags: jinja2

I just learned about Jinja's `include` function and wondered if it can also evaluate Jinja syntax within the loaded template?

So what I mean is something like:

view1.html

```
{% block content %}
{% include "subview1.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

subview1.html

```
{% for image in images %}
....
{% endfor %}
```

The [include](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#include) documentation states:

> Included templates have access to the variables of the active context by default.

And reading the [Import Context Behavior](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#import-context-behavior) information, I learned that

> By default, included templates are passed the current context, and imported templates are not.

So I conclude that the loaded templates can refer to the context of the main HTML. But it's not clear to me if they can also contain Jinja logic. Although I suspect it won't work since the templates are rendered first and then included.

> The include tag is useful to include a template and return the rendered contents of that file into the current namespace

Comment: Yes it can, but honestly testing it would have been quicker than writing this question.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I realized that midway. But then I just finished it as I 1) honestly could not find the answer by Googling it 2) failed to make it work with JS's `load()` function, unsure if it was due to my implementation or because it is not supposed to work.